# App crashes when passing Bluetooth mac address to 3rd activity in android

Tags: java, android, string, arduino, bluetooth

i'm trying to make a smart home application via bluetooth and arduino module So i made a 1st activity for bluetooth device list to be selected which is called " SelectBluetoothDeviceActivity ", and it works fine and i can easily find the required module on it and when i press on the selected device it goes to the second Activity which is called " MainActivity " with the module's mac address using intent.putExtra() method.
And it works all good by far and i can easily turn off and turn on the LED using my phone But when i want to go to the 3rd Activity which is called " TestActivity ", the app keeps crashing,
I copy/pasted the exact same code from the 2nd activity into the 3rd activity but it keeps giving me error.

For example in 1st activity The intent code is sth like this :

`

```
 private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener myListClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            // Get the device MAC address, the last 17 chars in the View
            String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            // Make an intent to start next activity.
            Intent i = new Intent(SelectBluetoothDeviceActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

            //Change the activity.
            i.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, address); //this will be received at ledControl (class) Activity
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };
```

`

in the 2nd activity it receives the extra like this :

`

```
 Intent newint = getIntent();
        address = newint.getStringExtra(SelectBluetoothDeviceActivity.EXTRA_ADDRESS); //receive the address of the bluetooth device
```

`

Everything works fine by far, But when i pass this mac address from 2nd activity to 3rd like this :

`

```
Intent returnToFreK = new Intent(MainActivity.this, test.class);
                returnToFreK.putExtra("dawn",address);
                startActivity(returnToFreK);
```

`

And recieve it like this on 3rd :

`

```
   Intent newint = getIntent();
        address = newint.getStringExtra("dawn"); //receive the address of the bluetooth device
```

`

The app crashes.

The 1st activity :

`

```
 public class SelectBluetoothDeviceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //widgets
    Button btnPaired;
    ListView devicelist;
    //Bluetooth
    private BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = null;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    public static String EXTRA_ADDRESS = "device_address";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_bluetooth_device);

        //Calling widgets
        btnPaired = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        devicelist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        //if the device has bluetooth
        myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if(myBluetooth == null)
        {
            //Show a mensag. that the device has no bluetooth adapter
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Device Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //finish apk
            finish();
        }
        else if(!myBluetooth.isEnabled())
        {
            //Ask to the user turn the bluetooth on
            Intent turnBTon = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(turnBTon,1);
        }

        btnPaired.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                pairedDevicesList();
            }
        });

    }

    private void pairedDevicesList()
    {
        pairedDevices = myBluetooth.getBondedDevices();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

        if (pairedDevices.size()>0)
        {
            for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
            {
                list.add(bt.getName() + "\n" + bt.getAddress()); //Get the device's name and the address
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Paired Bluetooth Devices Found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        devicelist.setAdapter(adapter);
        devicelist.setOnItemClickListener(myListClickListener); //Method called when the device from the list is clicked

    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener myListClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            // Get the device MAC address, the last 17 chars in the View
            String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            // Make an intent to start next activity.
            Intent i = new Intent(SelectBluetoothDeviceActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

            //Change the activity.
            i.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, address); //this will be received at ledControl (class) Activity
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };




}
```

`

The 2nd activity :

`

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Button btnOn, btnOff, btnDis;
    Button On, Off, Discnt, Abt;
    String address = null;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
    BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = null;
    BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private boolean isBtConnected = false;
    //SPP UUID. Look for it
    static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent newint = getIntent();
        address = newint.getStringExtra(SelectBluetoothDeviceActivity.EXTRA_ADDRESS); //receive the address of the bluetooth device

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Handler gtx = new Handler();
        gtx.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                Intent returnToFreK = new Intent(MainActivity.this, test.class);
                returnToFreK.putExtra("dawn",address);
                startActivity(returnToFreK);

            }
        }, 10000);


        On = (Button)findViewById(R.id.on_btn);
        Off = (Button)findViewById(R.id.off_btn);
        Discnt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dis_btn);
        Abt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.abt_btn);

        new ConnectBT().execute(); //Call the class to connect

        //commands to be sent to bluetooth
        On.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                turnOnLed();      //method to turn on
            }
        });

        Off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                turnOffLed();   //method to turn off
            }
        });

        Discnt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Disconnect(); //close connection
            }
        });


    }

    private void Disconnect()
    {
        if (btSocket!=null) //If the btSocket is busy
        {
            try
            {
                btSocket.close(); //close connection
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            { msg("Error");}
        }
        finish(); //return to the first layout

    }

    private void turnOffLed()
    {
        if (btSocket!=null)
        {
            try
            {
                btSocket.getOutputStream().write("0".toString().getBytes());
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                msg("Error");
            }
        }
    }

    private void turnOnLed()
    {
        if (btSocket!=null)
        {
            try
            {
                btSocket.getOutputStream().write("1".toString().getBytes());
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                msg("Error");
            }
        }
    }

    // fast way to call Toast
    private void msg(String s)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }






    private class ConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>  // UI thread
    {
        private boolean ConnectSuccess = true; //if it's here, it's almost connected

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Connecting...", "Please wait!!!");  //show a progress dialog
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... devices) //while the progress dialog is shown, the connection is done in background
        {
            try
            {
                if (btSocket == null || !isBtConnected)
                {
                    myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();//get the mobile bluetooth device
                    BluetoothDevice dispositivo = myBluetooth.getRemoteDevice(address);//connects to the device's address and checks if it's available
                    btSocket = dispositivo.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);//create a RFCOMM (SPP) connection
                    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                    btSocket.connect();//start connection
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                ConnectSuccess = false;//if the try failed, you can check the exception here
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) //after the doInBackground, it checks if everything went fine
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (!ConnectSuccess)
            {
                msg("Connection Failed. Is it a SPP Bluetooth? Try again.");
                finish();
            }
            else
            {
                msg("Connected.");
                isBtConnected = true;
            }
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

`

the 3rd activity :

`

```
  public class test extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button On, Off, Discnt, Abt;
    String address = null;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
    BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = null;
    BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private boolean isBtConnected = false;
    //SPP UUID. Look for it
    static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent newint = getIntent();
        address = newint.getStringExtra("dawn"); //receive the address of the bluetooth device

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);


        On = (Button)findViewById(R.id.on_btn);
        Off = (Button)findViewById(R.id.off_btn);
        Discnt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dis_btn);
        Abt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.abt_btn);

        new test.ConnectBT().execute(); //Call the class to connect

        //commands to be sent to bluetooth
        On.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                turnOnLed();      //method to turn on
            }
        });

        Off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                turnOffLed();   //method to turn off
            }
        });

        Discnt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Disconnect(); //close connection
            }
        });


    }

    private void Disconnect()
    {
        if (btSocket!=null) //If the btSocket is busy
        {
            try
            {
                btSocket.close(); //close connection
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            { msg("Error");}
        }
        finish(); //return to the first layout

    }

    private void turnOffLed()
    {
        if (btSocket!=null)
        {
            try
            {
                btSocket.getOutputStream().write("0".toString().getBytes());
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                msg("Error");
            }
        }
    }

    private void turnOnLed()
    {
        if (btSocket!=null)
        {
            try
            {
                btSocket.getOutputStream().write("1".toString().getBytes());
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                msg("Error");
            }
        }
    }

    // fast way to call Toast
    private void msg(String s)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }






    private class ConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>  // UI thread
    {
        private boolean ConnectSuccess = true; //if it's here, it's almost connected

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(test.this, "Connecting...", "Please wait!!!");  //show a progress dialog
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... devices) //while the progress dialog is shown, the connection is done in background
        {
            try
            {
                if (btSocket == null || !isBtConnected)
                {
                    myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();//get the mobile bluetooth device
                    BluetoothDevice dispositivo = myBluetooth.getRemoteDevice(address);//connects to the device's address and checks if it's available
                    btSocket = dispositivo.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);//create a RFCOMM (SPP) connection
                    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                    btSocket.connect();//start connection
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                ConnectSuccess = false;//if the try failed, you can check the exception here
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) //after the doInBackground, it checks if everything went fine
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (!ConnectSuccess)
            {
                msg("Connection Failed. Is it a SPP Bluetooth? Try again.");
                finish();
            }
            else
            {
                msg("Connected.");
                isBtConnected = true;
            }
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

`

I tried to change the "     String address = null; " in the 3rd application to the manual Mac address i got from device list, but the error remains.

Comment: It's great you've provided so much code, but in your case (application crash) the most useful information would be the Logcat output - the error stacktrace. Please, update the question with that information.